# Updating a table in access if there has been an update in another table

Tags: vba, ms-access, listener

I just want to add a backend listener to my table in access in such a way that, if there is an update in one table, the other table should be automatically updated.

For example,
There is a table A, for which a text file is the input data. Every night a new text file will be pushed to the folder, according to which the content in table A will change(ex., for an employee id, the department will be updated through the text file).
So whenever there is an update in table A, the department in table B has to be automatically updated.
Table A and B are already created without any links. How do I add a backend listener in this case. Please help.
P.S: I am new to access, I only have worked with sql server

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You apparently have some procedure which updates table A based on a text file source.  Revise that procedure to also make the necessary changes to table B after it updates table A.  I don't understand why you should need some type of "backend listener" for this.

Comment: Hey HansUpThanks for the response, but there's no procedure. I just mapped the text file to the table, so that table will be updated when there's a file with different data, but with the same name. And I want table B to be updated when A is updated

Comment: Nuts.  I didn't understand table A is actually a link to the text file.  In that case, Access doesn't expose events you can capture to determine when the text file changes.  I would be tempted to make table B a query rather than an actual table so that it is always consistent with the current data in table A.  However, I have no idea whether that approach is practical in your situation.  It depends on the nature of table B.

Comment: hey HansUp. thank you! but B should be a table. table A( empid, name, department, class,etc) and Table B(empid,name,dept,account,etc). so, whenever there is an update n A.department, then the B.department also has to be updated!

Comment: I have created an update query and run it in access. How do i reopen it and see the contents in it! I can only run it, but cant edit it

Comment: Not sure what you're asking now.  In the query designer, switch to SQL View.  Is that what you want?